# Can a post request object be forwarded in another post request?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, post

I have the following situation. I get a request to my server. This is being handled by a java servlet. the java servlet calls a jsp file to create a html page. The servlet passes a request object to the jsp. 
From the html page people can click on buttons which do post requests to other pages.

I would like to be able to pass the original request object (with additional info) along to the next page.

1) Is this possible? (maybe create a javascript object from the request object?)

2) Am I going about this all wrong and should I be creating user sessions or something? I have no experience with this.

Thanks

EDIT:

I think an example might clear somethings up.

1) from an external site a post request is done to servlet A. In this servlet I do the following:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {  

String jsp = "WEB-INF/webpage.jsp";
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp);
rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

Then in the jsp I do this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
    <form method="post" action="http://myurl.com/servletB" target="_self">
            <% String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");%> 
            Hello <%= first_name %>
            What is your lastname: <input type="text" name="last_name">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But in the original request was more information then only the first_name. And in servlet B I need all the information from the original request + the last_name.

Comment: ***From the html page people can click on buttons which do post requests to other pages*** - Post requests will go only to server and not directly goes to other jsp pages

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional line `<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value=<%=first_name %>>`

```
<body> 
    <form method="post" action="http://myurl.com/servletB" target="_self">
        <% String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");%> 
        Hello <%= first_name %>

        <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value=<%=first_name%>>

        What is your lastname: <input type="text" name="last_name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Now you get the first_name in servlet by `request.getParameter("first_name");`

Comment: Hi, thanks. But my problem is I need the data back after the person clicked on the html page. So this is client side. I need to place something in the html/javascript.

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the functionality, I use this now. However if someone looks in the source code they can see the parameters. I would like to keep these private.

Comment: If you like to keep these private, then like bedrin said, you've to store it in session once you receive the data from client. As far as I know, no other way.. Maybe..

Comment: Okay I'll have a look if I can use sessions without loosing to much performance. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two different requests here - one GET for rendering the form and another POST for submitting the data to the server.

These two requsts are handled separatelly so you should store the information from the original request in the session.

Comment: I have added some parts of my code. I have no GET requests. Only POST. So if I'm understanding you correct this should be done in a session? 1) Do you have a good source where I can learn about this? 2) Does this effect performance a lot? I have high traffic volumes (>3 million per hour). Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You said you are using POST, I wouldn't use the [307 redirect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) as you may encounter some issues.  I would use sessions.

Comment: OP does not look for a redirect - he wants to pass the data from the one request which renders the form to another which handles the form submission